# TypeScript import syntax not translated to JS import syntax

Tags: typescript

I'm doing this in file `main.ts`:

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
```

(as in [this TypeScript sample](https://github.com/Sean-Bradley/Three.js-TypeScript-Boilerplate/blob/master/src/client/client.ts))

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./built",
      "allowJs": true,
      "target": "es2017",
      "noEmitOnError": true,
      "strict": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*"]
  }
```

When I build, the resulting `main.js` file says:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
```

... so it doesn't convert the simple `'three'` import syntax to the JS import syntax (`'./three.js'`). So, when I load my HTML in Google Chrome, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

I could use webpack, which would "inline" the imported library into my code. But I want to avoid webpack for now (trying to have fewer tool dependencies).

**How do I make my import work in Google Chrome?**

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module